# Make a single if-statement wait before executing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am trying to make Java wait for 1 second before evaluating an if statement to see if it should change a boolean.

I have it set up where if Rectangle r intersects Rectangle y, a boolean "Intersect" becomes true and r moves backwards. 1 second later, I want an if-statement to check if r is still intersecting y. If not, "Intersect" becomes false again and r stops moving backwards. How can I do this? These statements are in the same Thread and there is animation involved so `Thread.sleep()` hasn't worked as it makes the animation very jumpy.

Here is the snippets of code that are relevant to the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {

boolean p1Intersect=false;

private class Move1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {

if((p1horizontal.intersects(grass1)&&(hleft==true||hright==true)&&p1Intersect!=true) {  //Normal speed
        p1Speed = 5;
    }
if(p1horizontal.intersects(edge2)&&hleft==true) { //moves backwards after collision as long as p1Intersect = true
        p1Speed=-4;
        p1Intersect=true;
    }
if((p1horizontal.intersects(edge2)&&hleft==true)==false) { //This is the statement that I would like to wait for 1 second before executing
p1Intersect=false;
    }
```

Comment: animation and logic should be separated. animation should run in the event dispatch thread btw. Thread.sleep is what you should use. what triggers the animation?

Comment: @galchen: Are you suggesting that Thread.sleep(...) should be called in the event dispatch thread?

Comment: hell no. but the animation should go in the event dispatch and the sleep in the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In game design, try keeping logic in main thread (that is, I would avoid using a timer). I suggest the following solution:

When intersection is detected, store the system time in a long,
using `long intersectTime =  System.currentTimeMillis()` .

Now, in the second if statement, just check for the extra condition
`System.currentTimeMillis()-intersectTime>1000`
since 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, what you want to do is set a *timer* that will fire one second after your first event is detected. If, when that event fires, check to see whether your rectangles are still intersecting. If so, take whatever action you need at that point.

As you noticed, `Thread.sleep()` will halt the execution of your whole thread and nothing else will happen there. That will also make your animation jumpy.

Comment: +1: You might also be able to detect events that definitely mean you won't be wanting to fire the guarded statement, so allowing you to cancel the timer early. (Event-driven programming can get a bit complex, even if that's really because the underlying interactions are actually complicated in the first place.)